# Efficiently printing matching pairs of semordnilaps from a sorted list of words

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I'm working on the problem of printing all matching pairs of semordnilaps from a given alphabetically sorted list of words (or phrases) (assumed to be in lower case).

A **semordnilap** is defined as a word (or phrase) which spells a **different** word (or phrase) backwards.  So *'top'* (*'pot'* read backwards), *'avid'* (*'diva'* read backwards), and *'animal'* (*'lamina'* read backwards) are semordnilaps, as is *'semordnilap'* itself because it's *'palindromes'* read backwards, whereas *'tot'*, *'peep'*, *'radar'* are palindromes (words which read the same backwards) but not semordnilaps.  In this context a pair of words *'word1'* and *'word2'* **match** if *'word1'* is *'word2'* read backwards (and vice versa).

If the length of the input list is `N` then the solution will obviously have complexity `O(N(N-1)/2)` because there are `N(N-1)/2` different pairs that can be constructed.  Also, if the list is alphabetically sorted then it seems in the worst case all `N(N-1)/2` pairs must be examined to find all the matching pairs.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, than the straightforward way.  Here is my code, currently.

```
import io

def semordnilaps_in_text_file( file_path ):

    def pairup( alist ):
        for elem1 in range( len( alist ) ):
            for elem2 in range( elem1 + 1 , len( alist ) ):
                yield ( alist[elem1], alist[elem2] )

    def word_list( file_path ):
        thelist = []
        with io.open( file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8' ) as file:
            for line in file:
                thelist.append( line.strip() )
        return thelist

    for word1, word2 in pairup( word_list( file_path ) ):
        if word1[::-1] == word2:
            print '{} {}'.format( word1, word2 )
```

I tried this function with a list of (all lowercase) English words found [here](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt) (containing 109583 words), and after a several minutes managed to print the following 21 pairs, before I interrupted it.

```
abut tuba
ac ca
ados soda
agar raga
ah ha
ajar raja
al la
am ma
an na
animal lamina
ante etna
ape epa
are era
ares sera
as sa
assam massa
ate eta
avid diva
aw wa
bad dab
bag gab
```

Comment: Don't use `if word1[::-1] is word2`, as that will only test whether they refer to the same object, which they may, or may not. Use `if word1[::-1] == word2` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `==` there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the total number of pairs is actually n!/2(n-2)!

Comment: I'm talking about pairs as combinations, so `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` are the same pair.  In a set of `N` elements there are `N(N-1)/2` different pairs of elements.  If `X = {a,b,c,d}` then the pairs are `(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,c), (b,d), (c,d)`, and the number of these is `6 = 4(4-1)/2`.

Comment: @1.618 I just noticed you are right (I thought you meant `(2(n-2))!` in your denominator) - `n! / 2*(n-2)! = n(n-1)...2*1 / 2 * (n-2)(n-3)...2*1 = n(n-1)/2`.

Comment: Good point.  I was always bad at simplifying expressions with factorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the words you've seen.

```
def pairup(alist):
  seen = set()
  for word in alist:
    if word not in seen:
      # Haven't seen this one yet
      if word[::-1] in seen:
        # But we've seen its reverse, so we found a pair
        yield (word, word[::-1])
      # Now we've seen it
      seen.add(word)
```

Subtlety: Adding the newly found word to `seen` at the end avoids triggering the yield if a palindrome is encountered. Conversely, if you also want to detect palindromes, add the word to `seen` before checking whether the reflection is already there.

Also: it is unnecessary to read the words into a list to use that function. You could just provide it with an iterable, such as a list comprehension:

```
for word, drow in pairup(line.strip().lower()
                         for line in io.open(filepath, 'r')):
  print('{} {}'.format(word, drow))
```

Comment: Nice point.  That's really fast, the speedup is ... well I'll have to test this using `timeit`, but thanks a lot.

Comment: @JamesThompson: Takes 0.11 sec on my system (including python3 startup, which is about 0.03 sec.

Comment: From inside my 2.7.6 interpreter `timeit.timeit( wrapped, number=1000000 ) / 1000000` shows an average call time of `0.00015381241011619567 s`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you can do is to preprocess the words using a hash table. Palindromes have to have the same count of letters, so just make a dictionary mapping like this:

```
opt => [pot, top, opt]
```

Then you just iterate over the lists and repeat your slower method. This words because it still uses your O(N^2) algorithm, but makes N much, much smaller by only comparing things that have the potential to be semordnilaps. You could use the same idea based only on length, where all words of length three were in one bucket. That would look like this:

```
3 => [pot, top, opt, cat, act, tac, art, tar, hop, ...]
```

However, this would be much slower than having the key depending on the word composition, because using only length you'd be comparing top, pot and opt to all other three-letter words.

Here's some code that found 281 semordnilaps in under one second on my laptop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import collections

def xform(word):
   return ''.join(sorted(list(word)))

wordmap = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [])
for line in open('wordsEn.txt', 'r'):
    word = line.rstrip()
    key = xform(word)
    wordmap[key].append(word)

for key, words in wordmap.iteritems():
    for index1 in xrange(len(words)):
        for index2 in xrange(index1 + 1, len(words)):
            word1 = words[index1]
            word2 = words[index2]
            if word1[::-1] == word2:
                print word1, ' ', word2
```

Results are available from [here](http://pastebin.com/12VbrH7z).
It's probably worth noting that sorting the list of words doesn't really help you, because the the semordnilaps are going to be scattered throughout the list.

Comment: Thanks, there are 281 in total from this list, and it tallies with mine and with the results from using @rici's version of `pairup`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I am thinking there must be some argument using probability by which you are more likely to pickup matching pairs if the list was scrambled (as it were) so that the words are in random order than in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm not sure if I buy that. The algorithms we're talking about are deterministic and correct, which means that correctness of output shouldn't depend on the order of the input. Maybe we should try to test this?

Comment: I agree that the final list of pairs will be the same either way (provided the code is correct) but I was making a point about speed: perhaps some ordering of words in a list might lead to a faster identification of all the pairs than say an alphabetical ordering.  It's only a hunch, and maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I might do that, i.e. test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary here to access the words in O(1).

```
words=open('words.txt','r')
word_dict={} #dictionary to store all the words
for word in words:
    word = word.strip('\n')
    if word!=word[::-1]: #remove the palindromic words
        word_dict[word] = ''

for word in word_dict.keys():
    try:
        word_dict[word] = word[::-1]
        #delete the semordnilaps from dictionary
        del word_dict[word[::-1]] 
    except KeyError:
        #if word has no semordnilaps then remove it from dictionary
        del word_dict[word]

#word_dict is the desired dictionary
print word_dict,"\nTotal words: \n",len(word_dict)
```

I have used 'del' to remove the unwanted words from dictionary thereby reducing the time complexity and and 'exception handling' to access the words in O(1).
Hope it helps.